# Multiple select list instant search is working but need to keep <optgroup> tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML:

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="list" size="10">
  <optgroup label="Group A">
    <option>Apple</option>
    <option>Banana</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Group B">
    <option>Orange</option>
    <option>Kiwi</option>
  </optgroup>
</select><br>

<input type="text" id="findItem">
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(function() {

  var opts = jQuery('#list option').map(function() {
    return [[jQuery(this).text()]];
  });

  jQuery('#findItem').keyup(function() {

    var rxp = new RegExp(jQuery('#findItem').val(), 'i');
    var optlist = jQuery('#list').empty();

    opts.each(function() {
      if(rxp.test(this[0])) {
        optlist.append(jQuery('<option/>').text(this[0]));
      }
    });

  });

});
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/vou3oa58/

The instant search is working just fine, but the  titles disappear because empty() just removes all parent and children elements inside the  list. I want to keep groups while performing a search and displaying the matches.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a more structured data object to take into consideration the optgroup nesting when building your canonical "opts" list. For example, with your HTML snippet, opts might look like:

```
[{'label': 'Group A', opts: ['Apple',...]}, {'label': 'Group B', opts: [...]}, ..]
```

A loop to build this might look like:

```
var optList = [];
jQuery('#list optgroup').each(function() {
    var $group = $(this),
        optgroup = {'label': $group.attr('label'), opts: []};

    $group.find('option').each(function() {
        optgroup.opts.push(this.innerText);
    });

    optList.push(optgroup);
});
```

Then you just iterate through your new data comparing the internal "opts" array values to the input value... of course, building your new optgroup/option markup for any matches you find.

To reset the entire innerHTML of the list and replace it when the list is cleared:

```
var optionHTML = $("#list")[0].innerHTML;
```

then to reset the list:

```
$("#list").html(optionHTML);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try to rewrite the code based on your suggestion.